# Is this damage on the bottom bracket shell concerning? Viking lugged steel frame

Tags: bottom-bracket, frame-protection

[image]

I was given this frame, it is a '80-something lugged steel Viking. I want to build it up but I don't know if this small crack in the bottom bracket shell will be a problem. It looks like the paint is peeling back a little bit and there is a bit of rust and maybe a small crack between the left chainstay lug and the bottom bracket shell. Other than this spot there are quite a few paint chips but the frame seems to be in good shape.

Does anyone with more experience with these old steel frames know if this needs to be welded or just cleaned up a bit and repainted?

Comment: That's an interesting viewpoint - is the photo from the back, between the chainstays ?

Comment: yes, that's exactly right

Answer (score 3):

From here it's hard to tell if it's a crack through the steel or just in the paint. You need to take it all apart and bead- blast the area in order to clean and inspect it. It's probably too hard to tell otherwise, through the rust and paint. If you don't have a bead blaster, perhaps paint stripper and wire brushes might be sufficient. If that crack goes all the way through the steel then you will probably destroy it getting the BB apart.

Comment: I would take the BB out and see what it looks like on the inside of the shell too - it's got to come out for cleaning anyway.      Not sure if brazing would work on this - a proper framebuilder's opinion would be best.

Comment: Thank you, I will try stripping the paint off and taking out the bb and hopefully it will be easier to tell the extent of the damage. I'll remain hopeful though.